# TableView not selectable

Tags: ios5, uitableview

My TableView didn't coloring a cell blue when I click a cell. the InterfaceBuild has

```
Selection: Single Selection
Show Selection on Touch : YES
```

And my code in my table view controller is run when I tap the table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // code
}
```

### EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    NSString *item = (NSString *)[songList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Realized my problem was the following line in my cellForRowIndexPath function

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```